# CUDA 32 bit integer operations faster on Kepler than Maxwell?

Tags: optimization, cuda

I am optimizing a CUDA program i wrote, and want to find the fastest hardware to run it. The core of the program is doing 32 bit integer operations: AND, OR, XOR, ADD, SUB.

According to nvidia programming guide http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#arithmetic-instructions Kepler (3.x) is capable of 160 such operations per clock. And Maxwell (5.x) can only handle 128.

Given the same number of multiprocessors, and same frequency. Does that mean is that Kepler is 20% faster than Maxwell?

Comment: yes agree with Gregor, please be more precise and moreover, put a source code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Kepler and Maxwell are different architectures, which means that performance is not just `throughput * SMs * frequency`. There are potentially many different architectural differences which allow one or the other to achieve a higher percentage of peak performance on real problems. Anecdotally, on computationally bound codes, I've seen reported higher percentage of peak for Maxwell then for Kepler.

One other difference which may be important in your case is the LOP3 instruction. Quoting from [NVIDIA's blog](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/new-features-cuda-7-5/):

> A new LOP3 instruction is added to PTX assembly, supporting a range of
>   3-operand logic operations, such as A & B & C, A & B & ~C, A & B | C,
>   etc. This functionality, supported on Compute Capability 5.0 and
>   higher GPUs, can save instructions when performing complex logic
>   operations on multiple inputs. See section 8.7.7.6 of the PTX ISA
>   specification included with the CUDA Toolkit version 7.5.

So with LOP3 you can achieve 256 logical operations per clock per SM on Maxwell instead of 128.

Comment: it seems that the best way to determine will be buying some test cards, and measuring

Comment: How do you use LOP3 instruction ? Do we have to write device function in .cu files or should we dive into the .ptx files ?

Comment: @Jez Are you sure about the 256 ops per second? Lop3 is not listed in the arithmetic throughput table.
@Madhatter when compiling for CUDA architecture 5.0 or higher the compiler will already generate lop3 automatically for many cases. You can look at the generated PTX code e.g. with `nvcc --keep test.cu`